# VS Code NuGet Package Manager and Workspaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuget, vscode-extensions

I have recently gotten a new machine and am attempting to migrate my dev environment over to it.  I am using VS Code and have installed the NuGet Package Manager GUI extension.  When I open that extension and click the Load Package Versions button nothing happens.  In the lower left corner of VS I see a message that says 'No Project found in the selected Workspace!'.

I am not sure if related but when I run `node -v` I get v16.14.0 but in Help About VS Code shows Node.js: 14.16.0.

I also have my project on the D drive and not the C drive which is where things are installed. Does that make a difference?  Did I miss adding something to the path that was needed?

I have searched and can't seem to find anyone else having this issue.  What can I try next?

Comment: hm, i am not aware the i need another tool to install packages in vs code nuget i only use in visual studio 2019/2017